# Announcer badge - How does it know I posted the link?

Tags: support, badges

So I was on another website (reddit.com) recently and someone had asked a programming question in one of the forums there. I quickly found an answer on this site (stackoverflow.com) and posted a link to the question as a reply.

A couple of hours later I logged-in to stackoverflow again and was notified that I had received the 'Announcer' badge. The 'Announcer' badge basically says that if you post a link on *another* website and it is viewed 25 times you get the badge.

My question is: How did Stackoverflow know that I posted the link on another website and how did it link the 25 clicks by other users to me?

Comment: It's a sekrit and on a need to know basis. :P  Kidding aside, I've wondered this as well.

Comment: Can't close as a duplicate of the blog, but [Announcer, Booster, and Publicist Badges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) should answer your question.  Some of the specific details have changed, but the process is the same.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The "share" link at the bottom of a post gives you a personalized URL.  For example, mine for your question is `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215549/162102`, but yours would have a different final number.  That number is the user number.

Since the URLs are unique, the server can log them separately.  Note that you *won't* get an Announcer badge for using the main URL of a page (like `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215549/announcer-badge-how-does-it-know-i-posted-the-link`) no matter how many people click on it.

See also: [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) (the badge criteria have changed since then, but this is mostly still applicable).

Comment: I know from conversations here and in chat that concerns about backticks are a *thing* on SO, but I'm not there and don't know what the issue is.  If I should have formatted those URLs some other way (to prevent prettification), please accept my apology and feel free to edit.

Comment: Really? The way you've formatted the URLs is the way I would have

Comment: Ahh! I think people object to them being used to `emphasise` important words, but a URL is a kind of code so I think backticks are very appropriate

Comment: Newer users on a number of SE sites have a bad habit of using `code` formatting where they ought to be using *italic* or **bold**. Use of backticks to encode an example URL is correct and well within site norms.

Comment: The Badge says "if you post a link on *another* website". Does this mean that if you would [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215549/208802) your share url instead of `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215549/208802` it. It wouldn't count as a view when opened from this site?

Comment: Links from within the Stack Exchange network don't count (including cross-site links).

Comment: Can a user somehow know location of the link which he/she presumably shared? For example, I don't remember where and when I posted links to SO questions (oops, found similar question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279428/announcer-badge-list-to-show-referrers-to-the-question)).

Comment: @Stan no, SE can't tell you what the referrer URLs were.  You'll need to either apply Google to the problem or live with the mystery.

Answer (score 12):

The share link embeds your userID in the link, for example if I share this post I get this link

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215549/220332
```

My userID is 220332 which you can see in the link

Only the share button gives you links that will count towards those badges

[image]