# Would appending one's user ID to the main url still make link count for the Announcer badge?

Tags: support, badges, hyperlinks, publicity-badges

While the expectation is that the 'share' url will be used, in some cases one might want to use the longer main url. Would appending one's user ID make such a link count for the publicity badges (Announcer, Booster, Publicist)?

(I did notice that "/q/question_ID/question-title-text" works and that the question title text appears to be ignored [i.e., different text will still link to the question].)

Since even [answer links now count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123544/226495) and the title text appears to be ignored, I would guess that such links do count.

---

Somewhat related: ["Announcer badge - How does it know I posted the link?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215549/announcer-badge-how-does-it-know-i-posted-the-link)

Comment: This would make a good feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Announcer badge only works with the short URLs.

You *have* to use the form `http://sitename/a/answer_id/user_id` or `http://sitename/q/question_id/user_id` for the tracking to work.

When you use the form `/q/question_id/question-title-text` you are simply giving it an invalid user id; the link works and redirects, and someone with the user id *question-title-text* would get the announcer badge.. :-)