# Announcer Badge list to show referrers to the question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, publicity-badges

Profile  Badges > Announcer shows the question to which link(s) refer, but 
doesn't show the place when the link(s) are  located. I recently received Announcer Badge, but I don't remember where I posted a link to the question.

If referrer information is recorded, It will be good to see the link(s) location as well.

Comment: I don't think it knows. The link you post has an id in it - and loading that link ups the counter. You could post the same link to facebook, twitter, and reddit, then email it to ten friends.

Comment: @KateGregory: Referer header https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer is normally available in redirection request populated by the browser. If SO stores it anyway, it is worth to show in Announcer list. If it is not recorded, my suggestion is not  important  to start do it.

Answer (score 10):

We do store referrer, but not in a way that's easily or sanely accessible from the Q&A sites (it's just in the traffic logs) nor is it necessarily connected to the badge awards (the badges are per-IP, not per source, so outside of curiosity we don't really care *where* people came from so long as they did at all).

This would require building out something new to track and display this info when it's available at all, and given the current badge numbers on SO (vs the actual # of visits/page views we get per day), I'm not sure it's all that worth it in terms of either dev time or storage cost.

Having said that, in the case of your recent badge, I'm afraid there's nothing conclusive to say here. I figured I'd look up referrers on the day the badge was awarded... and they're all either NULL or Google search sites (and one that looks like a Google+ search? I'm not sure how that works; I don't use G+.). This is unfortunately gonna have to remain a mystery. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯